# Brightness icon on my Macbook Air moved down

Tags: mac, display

My cat stepped on my keyboard for a second and now when I use F1-F12 the icons are at the bottom of the screen instead of the middle. I don't know what my cat did but I want to fix it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6W4aG.jpg)

Comment: Can you post a picture? Are you referring to the touch bar's graphics? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: This is how my 2015 rMBP has always been.  Are you on a desktop or laptop? Which version of macOS are you running?

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct location for the brightness HUD: centred horizontally and below middle vertically.

Comment: When I first got my laptop it was in the direct center of the screen